# Is a 64 bit system safer than a 32 bit one, because there are less exploits for them

Tags: security, assembly

Most books and papers on writing software exploits are written for the x86 processor family.
So there are probably a lot of "hackers" or crackers that only know x86 assembly.

Can you conclude from this, that 64 bit software is safer than 32 bit?

Comment: I am not voting to close, but this is one of these questions that comes with enough implicit assumptions to make it borderline. First and foremost, the amd64 instruction set is remarkably easy to pick up if you already know IA32. By design: it was intended to limit duplication on processors that were going to interpret both efficiently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The x86_64 CPUs out there can run x86 (32bit) code natively, and most operating systems that cater for x86_64 allow this (optionally or not, transparently or not).

You get all the attack vectors that existed for x86, plus anything else that was added with x86_64.

But the x86_64 generation of chips also brought security features like the NX bit. This type of thing can help reducing risk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. 64bit OSes get more common these days, so there will be exploits in the near future too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is security through obscurity, and in your particular question, it's not security at all.